# What is better to say: 1. Wir gehen auf die gleiche Klasse. 2. Wir sind in der gleichen Klasse?

Tags: meaning

1. Wir gehen auf die gleiche Klasse.
2. Wir sind in der gleichen Klasse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **W**ir gehen **auf**/in die gleiche Schule.
>
> **W**ir gehen <s>auf</s> **in** die gleiche Klasse.

Sorry about the confusion, but the preposition may be **auf** *or* **in** for the school but strictly only **in** for the class you attend within that school.

The reason for this is the school may be meant as an institution (preposition: **auf**) or the physical direction/place (preposition: **in**). There is no such difference made for the class, the course and other smaller entities within. It's often tricky to know. To make it even more confusing, there are also physical directions/places which strictly require **auf**, flat things as *der Hof*, and *das Dach* which you could stand upon.

> Wir gehen **auf** den Schulhof.

Others like *die Straße* are even more tricky:

> Sie gehen **auf** die Straße. *(leaving a building, entering the street)*
>
> Gehen Sie **in** die rechte Straße. *(giving directions on the street)*

German is a  *– censored –*.

---

> **W**ir sind **in** der gleichen **K**lasse.

Also correct and not better or worse than the other. It's a place (**in**+dative) rather than a direction as above with *gehen* (needs **auf**+accusative or **in**+accusative) so people will get a more static picture about what you tell.

Comment: But could it be dialect? It sounds vaguely familiar… maybe somewhere in southern Germany?

Comment: It's better for foreign speakers not to learn a dialect because you can hardly use it in writing. Writing dialect is not too common. Also speaking/writing only the parts of a dialect which come in handy to you makes it actually not better.

Comment: @Philipp, I'm from the Southwest and "wir gehen auf die gleiche Klasse" just sounds wrong.

Comment: In Austria: Only *»in«* for *Klasse* AND *Schule*. »Wir gehen *auf* die gleiche Schule.« sounds wrong in Austria. Also note, that »Ich gehe zur Schule« is not very common in Austria. Austrian children don't just walk to the school, they also enter it. So in Austria you say »Ich gehe in die Schule«.

Comment: @Iris Okay, thanks. I don't know, maybe I was mixing it up with other uses of »auf«, like »auf dieselbe Schule«. From my experience with relatives in Stuttgart, Mössingen and Freudenstadt (but myself being born in Hamburg), I believe that »auf« is used more frequently in Schwaben than in Hamburg.

Comment: @Philipp I'm from Stuttgart/ Herrenberg/ Calw. "Auf derselben Schule sein" is very common.

Comment: @Iris How about »auf dieselbe Stufe gehen«? That's at least similar to *Klasse*.

Comment: @Phillip, I would say »in derselben Stufe sein«. »auf dieselbe Stufe gehen« sounds strange, but not immediately wrong.